# what is "a" after a class in css?

Tags: html, css

So i am relatively new to CSS so im sorry if this question is a stupid one but what is "a" that is written after a class as seen below?

```
    .topnav {
  background-color:  black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}


.topnav a {
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 35px 20px;
  
  font-size: 21px;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-decoration: underline 0.10em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);

}


.topnav a:hover {
  
  
  background-color:rgb(59, 59, 59);
  transition:text-decoration 300ms;
  
 
  text-decoration-color: white;
}
```

Comment: It is the `<a>` tag which is used to create a hyperlink inside the HTML, to which this stylesheet is linked. The CSS helps to style it. The fact that it is after the class means that this styling should apply only to all the links inside that divider(`<div>`, `<span>`, etc.) and not the entire webpage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's every `<a>` tag inside the element with the class name. In this case it's every `<a>`inside `.topnav` element. If you are not sure, I like to set borders in CSS and then you can see what is affected by the CSS rule and what is not

```css
.topnav a {
  border: solid 2px fuchsia;

}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a>fuchsia border</a>
  <div class="hey">
     <a>fuchsia border</a>
  </div>
</div>
<a>not affected</a>
```

[CSS: Cascading Style Sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) it's definitely worth a read (start with the tutorials)

Answer (score 1):

It denotes the  tag inside another HTML element with the class name topnav. For an example, it may look like this:

```
<div class="topnav">
     <a>Link 1 </a>
</div>
```

a tag has specific properties like hover which denotes the different aspects of the tag

Answer (score 1):

im assuming you are talking about the `a` in the `.topnav a`

it means its styling the `<a>` tag in the element with the class `topnav`

for example i have a div with class of `topnav` and it has an `<a>` tag inside it like this

```html
<div class= "topnav">
   <a>hi</a>
</div>
```

the `.topnav a` in css will apply the style to this `<a>hi</a>` element